# Sense if a user is currently on a call when an incoming call comes?

Tags: busyindicator

I looked but I don't see this answered anywhere, or at least not answered using any keywords I can think of...

I just want to have a call come in, have the code look at the user it is intended for and, if the user is currently on another call, have it go off into a voicemail. I am pretty sure I can do everything except have the system sense that the intended user is currently busy with another call... Is there a way to sense this or do I have to implement a flag or something in a database to flip on or off at the start of a call and the hangup?

Comment: Android, iOS, Win-phone, other?

Comment: I am doing this in PHP server side.

Comment: I mean, I could just store a flag in a database somewhere that gets flipped to "On" when a call comes in and "Off" when the call ends and all... But that feels really clunky to me. If there is a simple function call somewhere where I can just do a check, it seems like that'd be a lot cleaner...